# Firebase-realtime-database how to return the data within a nested child node as a list

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, async-await

I'm building a mood logging app using Xamarin forms for a university project but i've hit a wall when trying to return the data contained within a nested child node. Please see my firebase schema below:

BrainBreakApp

- MoodLog #1

  - *unique MoodLog id assigned by firebase*

    - Mood Rating
    - Note
    - Location
    - Activities

      - *Unique activity id assigned by firebase*

        - activity logged by user (e.g. **Shopping**)
      - *Unique activity id assigned by firebase*

        - activity logged by user (e.g. **Working**)
- MoodLog #2
- MoodLog #3
  etc.

---

I'm easily able to return all of the data within each mood log, except the data within the 'Activities' child node. I have placed 'shopping' and 'working' in bold because that is the data I need to return.

In my 'MoodLog' model, I have declared the 'Activities' attribute as a list of type 'Activity'; which is a separate model just containing an 'ActivityName' attribute. As my current code stands I need to return all of the activities for that particular log in a list that I can assign to the MoodLog 'Activities' attribute.

I've tried a number of approaches including adding the statement to return the list within the 'Activity' assignment and generating a list of the activities for each emotion log separately and assigning the returned list to 'Activity'; but clearly no luck. The issue i'm continually running into when trying to create a separate list of activities for that emotion log, is being able to access the firebase generated key for that particular log each time, and also being able to return a List<> type rather than a Task List<> type that I can't assign to the 'Activity' attribute. 
I appreciate that much of the documentation states to make the schema as flat as possible, and if you can think of a flatter schema that will serve the same purpose that would also be fantastic.

I'm a complete Firebase newbie so any help at all would be very much appreciated!
I'll place my current code below and you will see where I need to add the list of activities:

```
public async Task<List<EmotionLog>> GetAllLogsForPerson()
        {
            var allPersons = await GetAllLogs();
            await Firebase
                .Child(LogChildName)
                .OnceAsync<EmotionLog>();
            return allPersons.Where(a => a.UserId == personId).ToList();
        }


public async Task<List<EmotionLog>> GetAllLogs()
           {
            return (await Firebase
                .Child(LogChildName)
                .OnceAsync<EmotionLog>()).Select(item => new EmotionLog
                {
                    UserId = item.Object.UserId,
                    DateTime = item.Object.DateTime,
                    Note = item.Object.Note,
                    Location = item.Object.Location,
                    MoodRating = item.Object.MoodRating,
                    NoActivities = item.Object.NoActivities,
                    Activity =
                    {
                      // Need to add list of activities here
                    }
                }).ToList();
          }
```

**EDIT:**

Please see the code below used to post the emotion log data to the firebase db. I add all of the other log data first in the 'AddLog' method, and then iterate separately through the activities using the 'AddActivity' method, which is called within the 'Add Log' method.

```
public async Task AddLog(string Id, string Note, string Location, DateTime DateTime, int MoodRating, List<string> ActivityList)
    {
        await Firebase
            .Child(LogChildName)
            .PostAsync(new EmotionLog() { UserId = Id, Note = Note, Location = Location, DateTime = DateTime, MoodRating = MoodRating});

       await AddActivity(Id, ActivityList);
    }

 public async Task AddActivity(string Id, List<string> ActivityList)
    {
        var toAddUserActivities = (await Firebase
            .Child(LogChildName)
            .OnceAsync<EmotionLog>()).Last(a => a.Object.UserId == Id);

        foreach (string item in ActivityList)
        {
            await Firebase
            .Child(LogChildName)
            .Child(toAddUserActivities.Key)
            .Child(ActivityChildName)
            .PostAsync(new Activity() { ActivityName = item });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know Xamarin but I use Firebase RTDB from Flutter/Dart. You haven't posted the code that creates the database nodes so I am assuming there is a .push somewhere that you are using to create the unique ids for the activities. However, if you simply want a list of activity names held against each MoodLog and they never need to have other attributes or be referenced by an Id then you don't need to have Firebase create the Id. You can simply save the list/array of activity names as an array on the db and retrieve it the same way, then iterate through it to get your activity names.

Comment: Have a look at https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the response @GrahamD! I didn't realise that I could just get rid of the ID's, but once I did it all just worked! Thanks so much again :)

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Comment: You can write your solution in the answer and mark it so that you can help more people with same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove the unique Id assigned to each activity within the database. These were being generating because rather than just adding my activity list to the emotion log as one whole list, i was iterating through the list and adding each of them to the emotion log individually.

Once i removed the code that iterated through the activity list and changed my list to type List, everything worked perfectly :)